# How to set kCISamplerAffineMatrix when creating CISampler with image

Tags: macos, core-image, cifilter

## Problem

I am trying to create a CISampler from an image with additional options which specify the affine matrix. The docs state the following to set the kCISamplerAffineMatrix:

> The associated value is an NSArray object ([a b c d tx ty]) that defines the transformation to apply to the sampler.

## Attempt

```
NSArray *flipVertically = @[@(1),@(0),@(0),@(-1),@(0),@(0)];
NSDictionary *optionsDict = @{ kCISamplerAffineMatrix: flipVertically };
CISampler *sampler = [CISampler samplerWithImage:image options:optionsDict];
```

## Attempt #2

```
CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformMake(1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0);
CIVector *vector = [CIVector vectorWithCGAffineTransform:transform];
NSDictionary *optionsDict = @{ kCISamplerWrapMode:  kCISamplerWrapClamp, kCISamplerAffineMatrix: vector };
CISampler *sampler = [CISampler samplerWithImage:image options:optionsDict];
```

## Result

Instead of having a flipped affine matrix in the sampler it is the same as the the CIImage's matrix. I can however set the kCISamplerWrapMode without problems which makes me think that I somehow don't understand the documentation's description of how to set the matrix. What is an NSArray object ([a b c d tx ty])? when I print the matrix in the console I get `[1 0 0 1 0 0]` but my NSArray of corse looks more like `(1,0,0,-1,0,0)`.

Comment: I'm pretty much strictly Swift (I use several other languages and can read Obj-C) and have not tried `CISampler`, so forgive me is this sounds stupid. Are you computing the "flipped" Y axis correctly? In CoreImage the origin `CGPoint(0,0)` is the *lower* right, not upper.

Comment: Yeah the original matrix of the CIImage is [1 0 0 -1 0 <imageHeight>] so the correct flipped matrix of that would be [1 0 0 1 0 0] i think. Nontheless I‘m not able to set the matrix.

Comment: I know the docs say `NSArray`, but have you tried passing an `NSValue` or `CIVector` wrapping a `CGAffineTransform` instead?

Comment: I have not thought about that yet. Tried it now with `CIVector`, this does also not change my resulting sampler's affine matrix neither by passing the `CIVector` directly nor by wrapping the vector in an `NSArray`. When wrapping the `CIVector` I'm not even sure if I'm wrapping it correctly, since there is no `NSValue` method `valueWithCIAffineTransform`. I tried `valueWithPointer` and passing a pointer to my affine transform, but that does not change the results in the sampler. But thanks for the hint.

Comment: I was thinking about either `[CIVector vectorWithCGAffineTransform:]` or `[NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:]` and passing a `CGAffineTransform` containing your values.

Comment: unless we're building for different build targets, there does not seem to be a `[NSValue valueWithCGAffineTransform:]`. The closest would be a Core Animation transform `[NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:]`. For now I can do the mirroring within the actual filter code, but passing the transform would have been nice for more complex distortions.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't realize that those APIs are not available on macOS...